# How to capture suddenly destructed TThread

Tags: delphi, c++builder, tthread

```
My Environment: Rad Studio XE4 using C++
```

I am working on a software using TThread. Recently, I am facing a problem in which the TThread is suddenly destructed after several days from the program start.

In the TThread, the thread changes displays of forms (e.g. TLables) using Synchronize() method. I wonder this might cause some problem.

I am logging at several parts in the thread so that I can catch the cause of the problem. But when I check the log, I can only find that the destructor of the TThread is suddenly called.

The FreeOnTerminate of the TThread is set as true.

The program runs two threads. Only one thread is destructed suddenly and the other thread is working even after the problem occurs.

I am searching the way how to catch the cause of this kind of problem.

Comment: Add madExcept and get some more debugging

Comment: and write some logging code. Clearly you are terminating your thread.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did not know the madExcept. I wrote my logging code at http://qiita.com/7of9/items/3837e529237c862f670c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> when I check the log, I can only find that the destructor of the TThread is suddenly called.

The **only** way that can happen is:

1. If you are setting the thread's `FreeOnTerminate` property to true (which you are) and your thread is terminating due to its `Execute()` method exiting (either because it encountered a `return` statement, reached the end of its code, or threw an exception you did not catch).  To log if the thread is terminating, you can override its virtual `DoTerminate()` method, or assign an `OnTerminate` event handler to it.
2. If some piece of code outside of the thread is calling `delete` on the thread object pointer. To log if this is happening, you will have to log your `delete` calls.

Given that you *are* setting `FreeOnTerminate` to true, then the likely culprit is `Execute()` exiting due to an uncaught exception.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In my code, I do not delete Tthread object by myself. The TThread is constructed when the software start, and destructed when the software stops for normal operation. So it seems that the uncaught exception is causing this problem as you wrote. I will consider to catch the exception somehow to solve the problem (maybe try, catch and debug output the error message).

Comment: I will also study DoTerminate() and OnTerminate event hanlder as you suggest.